# TouchDragOutside on a UIButton not firing until touch is around 5-10px away

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uibutton, touch-event

I'm using TouchDragOutside on a UIButton that I placed in IB, but it isn't firing until I have  moved around 8px vertically away and 2 horizontally. The button dimensions (reading out from the IB inspector) are 50 wide and 35 high. I don't really understand!

Is there a way to check/set what the bounds of the button actually are? Do I need to set the bounds differently for touchdragoutside?

Has anybody else encountered this problem or is this part of the way touchdragoutside is designed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably by design, next time you use a navigation bar try clicking slightly outside of your intended button, and you will notice that even though you are outside of your button it is still clickable. Apple does this to make user interaction easier and I'd be willing to bet that what you're experiencing is part of the same design concept, giving the user a "buffer" to decide to cancel the `TouchDragOutside` before it fires.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense sadly. It also explains the discrepancy between the gap vertically and horizontally - my view is landscape, so a user is more likely to miss vertically, hence the 16px difference.

Comment: Hmm...I will have to think of an alternative solution